# Java 8 Function - Incompatible Types

Tags: java, java-8

I am attempting to assign a java 8 function pointer to a variable but get an incompatible type error when building.  It appears that the compiler is not respecting "? extends BaseEntity".

For the below code ChildEntity directly extends BaseEntity:

```
private int getValue(ChildEntity entity) {
    return 0;
}

Function<? extends BaseEntity, ?> function = this::getValue;
```

Error: Base entity can not be converted to a ChildEntity.

Comment: Can you show a bit more please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about how `function` will be used.  You are going to pass into it an object of any type that inherits from `BaseEntity`.

Imagine `SpouseEntity` also derives directly from `BaseEntity`.  Would you be able to pass that `SpouseEntity` into a method that requires a `ChildEntity`?

No, you would not, because `SpouseEntity` did not derive from `ChildEntity`.

In other words, the method pointed to by a function pointer must have its parameters be no more derived than those declared in the function pointer itself.  The function pointer parameters must derive from, or be identical to, those declared in the method it points to.

(Note that return type works the exact opposite way, which is why `super` exists, because the return type of a method must inherit from or be identical to the return type of its function pointer).

Comment: I don't agree with the first sentence. With 'super' it's about passing any superclass of BaseEntity, not any type that inherits from it.

Comment: @Maaaatt - I don't see any mention of "super" in my answer or the question tbh.

Comment: "Think about how function will be used. You are going to pass into it an object of any type that inherits from BaseEntity."

Before the post edit, it was mentioned Function<? super BaseEntity, ?> so meaning the function as such is expecting a Superclass instance of BaseEntity or an instance of BaseEntity

Comment: @Maaaatt - that wouldn't work for the same reason.  A function pointer is only compatible with a method if the pointer specifies parameters that are at least as derived as those declared on the method being pointed to.  But I see your (now moot by edit) point and would upvote if I weren't out of upvotes.

Comment: I agree with that. My point is that his issue was maybe more with the definition of getValue than with the Function declaration.

Comment: @Maaaatt - DERP!  My bad I'm sorry!  I hate it when I'm dense.

Comment: No worries! At least we clarified the situation :)

Answer (score 2):

ChildEntity extends BaseEntity, so not *everything* that extends BaseEntity is a valid argument to your Function. You could do:

```
Function<ChildEntity, int> function = this::getValue;
```

or

```
Function<? extends ChildEntity, int> function = this::getValue;
```

Answer (score 1):

`? super BaseEntity` will not work because `BaseEntity` does not extend `ChildEntity` (in fact the opposite is true).

`? extends BaseEntity` will not work because we don't really know what type of `BaseEntity` will be accepted by the function.  As the caller, I don't know whether it is safe to pass a `ChildEntity`, a `BaseEntity`, a `SomeOtherTypeOfEntity`, or anything else.

Answer (score -2):

Remeber `this` keyword applies to the class you are currently working in. So unless BaseEntity has the method `getValue(ChildEntity)` anything that extends BaseEntity would likely not work.  Change the function to require a class that extends ChildEntity.  You are also missing your return type.